# FoldRight in Laziness in scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

```
def foldRight[B] (z : =>B) (f :(A, =>B) => B) :B

def headOptionViaFoldRight():Option[A]=foldRight(None:Option[A])((h,t)=> Some(h()))

def takeWhileViaFoldRight(f:A=>Boolean):Stream[A]=foldRight(Stream[A]())((h,t)=> Some(h))

def forAll(p:A=>Boolean):Boolean=foldRight(true)((a,b)=>p(a)&&b)
```

Why None: Option[A] in the first parameter in headOptionViaFoldRight?

Why Stream[A] in the first parameter in takeWhileViaFoldRight?

Why true in the first parameter in forAll?

Just confused on what to use in the first parameter in foldRight?

Answer (score 1):

> Just confused on what to use in the first parameter in foldRight?

The initial value: what you'd get on an empty sequence.

Answer (score 1):

> Why true in the first parameter in forAll?

It is by convention, and historical precedent, that `exists()`  on an empty collection returns `false` while `forall()` on an empty collection returns `true`.